# It's still possible to get the email hash

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

I noticed that its still possible to get the email hash from users, even though it **was** removed.

Like this:

---

Hello, user, I want your chat account link

*User passes in link*

*Regex magic happens*

We get this link:

```
http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/thumbs/1
```

Which returns something like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jeff Atwood",
    "email_hash": "JEFF'S EMAIL HASH",
    "last_seen": 1436370901,
    "last_post": 1398102945,
    "rooms": [],
    "usage": null,
    "user_message": "benevolent dictator for life. well, mostly.",
    "is_moderator": true,
    "is_registered": true,
    "reputation": 254465,
    "profileUrl": "//meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood",
    "site": {
        "icon": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchangemeta/img/favicon.ico",
        "caption": "Meta Stack Exchange"
    },
    "invite_targets": [
        {
            "id": 721,
            "name": "Shadow&#39;s Den"
        }
    ],
    "host": "meta.stackexchange.com",
    "may_pairoff": true,
    "issues": null
}
```

Shouldn't the `email_hash` be removed?

Comment: For those of us still using gravatar, you can pull the email hash anywhere our picture is displayed - no need to mess with chat. *Because that's how Gravatar works.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although the field is called `email_hash`, its real purpose is to hold information necessary for retrieving the user's profile picture.

- For those who uploaded an image on an SE site, it's a link to imgur.
- For those old-timers using Gravatar (hi Jeff), it's the hash part of the URL.

So, you see `51d623f33f8b83095db84ff35e15dbe8` for Jeff Atwood, because the URL of his gravatar is https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/51d623f33f8b83095db84ff35e15dbe8

And this gravatar is seen everywhere on the sites, so it's not necessary to do this trick with chat...